# Detect between app start up and returning from another page

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I am building a win 8 metro app. In my main page, I have to check settings when my app starts up. But if I navigate to another page and come back , I do not want it to execute again. How can I detect this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do something once when the app is launched, use the [Application.OnLaunched](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.onlaunched) method. It is already implemented in the App.xaml.cs and you can add your code there.

Comment: if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), arg.Arguments))   is it ok if i delete the arg.Arguments? or is it null to begin with?